# IIS 500 Error When Trying to Update WordPress Locally

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, xdebug

I am having a bit of a weird issue.

I am updating a plugin locally to test it doesn't break anything on a clients site but I keep getting 500 errors unless I am running the xdebug listener in PhpStorm. As soon as I turn on the listener the plugin updates perfectly.

[image: 500 Error]

These are the logs from inetpub:

```
2017-06-07 09:28:54 127.0.0.1 POST /wp-cron.php doing_wp_cron=1496826836.9809379577636718750000 80 - 127.0.0.1 WordPress/4.7.3;+http://www.example.local http://www.example.local/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1496826836.9809379577636718750000 500 0 64 897829
2017-06-07 09:33:00 127.0.0.1 POST /wp-admin/update-core.php action=do-translation-upgrade 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:53.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/53.0 http://www.example.local/wp-admin/update-core.php 500 0 258 781935
```

There is nothing in the PHP log.

This is my xdebug code from my php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
; XDEBUG Extension
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.3-5.6-vc11-nts.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\temp"
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

If I comment this out and restart IIS everything works fine.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if you have to escape the spaces in Program Files (x86) with a '\'. Is the client running PHP on windows in production?

Comment: If you get a 500, then somewhere, something was written to a log file.

Comment: @mkaatman no this is just my dev environment. Xdebug works just fine, and the site works as intended when the listener is enabled.

Comment: @castis I have updated with the logs